# .show jquery function - not displaying div

Tags: jquery, show-hide

I'm trying to make this javascript work, I want to show the hidden (display:none) div when the user clicks on the button. Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/tz52u/

Example is on the website above.

Code I'm using:

```
     $(document).ready(function () {
     $("#show").click(function () {
    $(".no-show").show();
    });
    });
```

Thanks for your help.

Really appreciated!

Comment: You have HTML `<script>` tags in the javascript field. See http://jsfiddle.net/tz52u/3/

Comment: Plese show all relevant code here, jsfiddle should be used for us to test not to view your code.

Comment: Works fine after solving the errors.

Comment: Aside from the syntax errors (use the jshint button at the top), you also forgot to include the Jquery libraries on the left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a `});` in your fiddle. Also you don't need the script tags in the fiddle either. Also you didn't include jQuery. Also you don't need the `$(document).ready()` because jsFiddle loads the code already.

Here's a fixed one:

http://jsfiddle.net/tz52u/6/

```
$("#show").click(function(){
    $(".no-show").show();
});
```

Comment: also, he didn't include jquery

Comment: Also, binding the `ready` event from the `load` event is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

You were using html tags `<script>` in the javascript field, which is already wrapped in jsfiddle to run on load.

You did not reference jQuery by selecting it to the left side, so `$` was undefined.

Also, you don't need the `$(document).ready()` anymore - jQuery now provides `$(function(){ console.log("Document is ready"); });` which is a more convenient way of executing code when the page is ready.

Here is a fixed version: http://jsfiddle.net/tz52u/9/

```
  $("#show").click(function(){
      console.log("Button clicked!");
    $(".no-show").show();
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Prevent the click handler from behaving normally:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#show").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".no-show").show();
  });
});
```